# There is any way to integrate Specflow with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, specflow

I recently look in the Jasmine framework and I need to known if exists any way to use Specflow language  to describe the behavior and Jasmine as TestRunner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specflow is cucumber for .net, so it won't be able to run javascript tests using jasmine.

However there are a couple of cucumber frameworks for javascript ([see this](http://transitioning.to/2012/01/cucumber-and-js-getting-started-with-cucumber-js/) and the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198798/bdd-framework-for-the-frontend) which also shows how jasmine expects the tests to be written BDD style.) which will give you natural language syntax used in SpecFlow for you javascript tests.

Comment: Yes I known this but is a little bit awkward to have both and I looking for any solution that allow me to use only one language for behavior description. Thanks anyway!

Comment: did you see the link for cucumber.js? that IS gerkin syntax, same as specflow

Comment: Yes I'm reviewing now that link, looks pretty similar